# Surface by pgfplot from data files

Tags: pgfplots

I try to plot surface by `pgfplot` from data files, but I have the problem as below picture

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{20}, grid=both]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort]
            table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=3] {test.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

test.txt data:

```
x   y   z
-2.00E-02   -1.32E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.32E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.32E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.31E-02   7.29E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.30E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.30E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.29E-02   7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.29E-02   7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.28E-02   1.01E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-02   8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-02   8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-02   1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-02   1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.26E-02   1.15E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.26E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.26E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.24E-02   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.24E-02   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.24E-02   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.24E-02   1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.24E-02   1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.23E-02   8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.23E-02   8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.22E-02   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-02   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.20E-02   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.20E-02   1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.20E-02   1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.19E-02   1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.19E-02   1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.18E-02   8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.18E-02   8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.18E-02   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.18E-02   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.18E-02   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.17E-02   1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.17E-02   1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.16E-02   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.16E-02   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.16E-02   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-02   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.13E-02   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.13E-02   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.13E-02   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.13E-02   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.13E-02   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.12E-02   9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.12E-02   9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.11E-02   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.11E-02   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.11E-02   1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.11E-02   1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.11E-02   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.10E-02   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.10E-02   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.10E-02   1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.10E-02   1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.08E-02   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.07E-02   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.05E-02   1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.04E-02   9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.04E-02   9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.04E-02   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.04E-02   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.03E-02   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.03E-02   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.02E-02   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.02E-02   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-02   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.96E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.96E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.85E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -9.85E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -9.84E-03   1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.84E-03   1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.81E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.81E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.79E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.79E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.76E-03   1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.76E-03   1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.72E-03   1.60E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.60E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.60E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.56E-03   9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   -9.56E-03   9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   -9.50E-03   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.50E-03   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.46E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.46E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.40E-03   1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.40E-03   1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.26E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.26E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.23E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.23E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.14E-03   1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.14E-03   1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.13E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.13E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.09E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.09E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.03E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.03E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.96E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.96E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.87E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -8.87E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -8.80E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.80E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.79E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.79E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.66E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.66E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.65E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.65E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.60E-03   9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   -8.60E-03   9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   -8.49E-03   1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.49E-03   1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.46E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.46E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.43E-03   1.69E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.42E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.42E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.34E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.34E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.32E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.32E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.11E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.11E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.05E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.05E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.04E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.04E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.02E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.02E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.89E-03   1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.89E-03   1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.80E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.80E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.79E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -7.79E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -7.76E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.76E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.75E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.75E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.70E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.70E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.54E-03   9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   -7.54E-03   9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   -7.46E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.46E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.40E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.40E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.37E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.37E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.29E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.29E-03   1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.26E-03   1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.26E-03   1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.17E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.17E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.16E-03   1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.16E-03   1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.13E-03   1.75E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.03E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.03E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.03E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.03E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.86E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.86E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.77E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.77E-03   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.69E-03   1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.69E-03   1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.63E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -6.63E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -6.59E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.59E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.56E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.56E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.51E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.51E-03   1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.50E-03   1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.50E-03   1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.45E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.45E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.41E-03   9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   -6.41E-03   9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   -6.24E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.24E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.24E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.24E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.18E-03   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.18E-03   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.96E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.96E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.96E-03   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.96E-03   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.92E-03   1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.92E-03   1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.86E-03   1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.86E-03   1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.80E-03   1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.80E-03   1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.75E-03   1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.75E-03   1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.73E-03   1.81E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.73E-03   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.73E-03   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.68E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.68E-03   1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.49E-03   1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.49E-03   1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.40E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.40E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.39E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -5.39E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -5.25E-03   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.25E-03   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.20E-03   8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   -5.20E-03   8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   -5.10E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.10E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.09E-03   1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.09E-03   1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.06E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.06E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.02E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.02E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.01E-03   1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.01E-03   1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.01E-03   1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.01E-03   1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.99E-03   1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.99E-03   1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.82E-03   1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.82E-03   1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.76E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.76E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.62E-03   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.62E-03   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.50E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.50E-03   1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.42E-03   1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.42E-03   1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.27E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.27E-03   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.27E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.27E-03   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.25E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.25E-03   1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.24E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.24E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.22E-03   1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.22E-03   1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.22E-03   1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.22E-03   1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.22E-03   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.09E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -4.09E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -4.01E-03   1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.01E-03   1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.95E-03   8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   -3.95E-03   8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   -3.80E-03   1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.80E-03   1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.79E-03   1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.79E-03   1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.64E-03   1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.64E-03   1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.58E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.58E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.48E-03   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.48E-03   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.44E-03   1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.44E-03   1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.44E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.44E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.42E-03   1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.42E-03   1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.42E-03   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.42E-03   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.41E-03   1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.41E-03   1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.36E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.36E-03   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.32E-03   1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.32E-03   1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.16E-03   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.16E-03   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.99E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.99E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.82E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.82E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.75E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -2.75E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -2.65E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.65E-03   1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.65E-03   8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   -2.65E-03   8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   -2.60E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.60E-03   1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.59E-03   1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.58E-03   1.90E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.55E-03   1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.55E-03   1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.54E-03   1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.54E-03   1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.48E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.48E-03   1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.43E-03   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.43E-03   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.32E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.32E-03   1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.21E-03   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.21E-03   1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.09E-03   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.09E-03   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.97E-03   1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.97E-03   1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.85E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.85E-03   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.74E-03   1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.73E-03   1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.73E-03   1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.73E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.73E-03   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.72E-03   1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.72E-03   1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.68E-03   1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.68E-03   1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.61E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.61E-03   1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.39E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.39E-03   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.33E-03   7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.33E-03   7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-03   1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.27E-03   1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-03   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.21E-03   1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-03   1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.15E-03   1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.09E-03   1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.09E-03   1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.03E-03   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.03E-03   1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.70E-04   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.70E-04   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.06E-04   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.06E-04   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.72E-04   1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.72E-04   1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.72E-04   1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.72E-04   1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.71E-04   1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.71E-04   1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.70E-04   1.92E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.67E-04   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.67E-04   1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.52E-04   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.52E-04   1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.41E-04   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.41E-04   1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.23E-04   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.23E-04   1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.74E-04   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.74E-04   1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.04E-09   0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.03E-09   7.29E+00
-2.00E-02   -1.01E-09   1.01E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.92E-10   1.15E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.74E-10   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.56E-10   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.38E-10   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.19E-10   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.00E-10   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.81E-10   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.61E-10   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.58E-10   1.60E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.68E-10   1.69E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.81E-10   1.75E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.93E-10   1.81E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.03E-10   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.14E-10   1.90E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.30E-10   1.92E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.58E-10   1.92E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.00E-10   1.90E+01
-2.00E-02   -9.09E-11   1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.10E-11   1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.42E-11   1.60E+01
-2.00E-02   -7.13E-11   1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.20E-11   1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   -6.18E-11   1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.50E-11   1.69E+01
-2.00E-02   -5.25E-11   1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.34E-11   1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.33E-11   1.81E+01
-2.00E-02   -4.24E-11   1.75E+01
-2.00E-02   -3.44E-11   1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   -2.55E-11   1.15E+01
-2.00E-02   -1.69E-11   1.01E+01
-2.00E-02   -8.36E-12   7.29E+00
-2.00E-02   1.62E-18    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   7.74E-04    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   7.74E-04    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   8.23E-04    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   8.23E-04    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   8.41E-04    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   8.41E-04    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   8.52E-04    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   8.52E-04    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   8.67E-04    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   8.67E-04    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   8.70E-04    1.92E+01
-2.00E-02   8.71E-04    1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   8.71E-04    1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   8.72E-04    1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   8.72E-04    1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   8.72E-04    1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   8.72E-04    1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   9.06E-04    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   9.06E-04    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   9.70E-04    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   9.70E-04    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.03E-03    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.03E-03    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.09E-03    1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   1.09E-03    1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-03    1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-03    1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-03    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-03    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.27E-03    1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   1.27E-03    1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   1.33E-03    7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   1.33E-03    7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   1.39E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.39E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.61E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   1.61E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   1.68E-03    1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   1.68E-03    1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   1.72E-03    1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   1.72E-03    1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   1.73E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.73E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.73E-03    1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   1.73E-03    1.91E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   1.74E-03    1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   1.85E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.85E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.97E-03    1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   1.97E-03    1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   2.09E-03    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   2.09E-03    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   2.21E-03    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   2.21E-03    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   2.32E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   2.32E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   2.43E-03    1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   2.43E-03    1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   2.48E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   2.48E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   2.54E-03    1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   2.54E-03    1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   2.55E-03    1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   2.55E-03    1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   2.58E-03    1.90E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.89E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   2.59E-03    1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   2.60E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   2.60E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   2.65E-03    8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   2.65E-03    8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   2.65E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   2.65E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   2.75E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   2.75E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   2.82E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   2.82E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   2.99E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   2.99E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   3.16E-03    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   3.16E-03    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   3.32E-03    1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   3.32E-03    1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   3.36E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   3.36E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   3.41E-03    1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   3.41E-03    1.88E+01
-2.00E-02   3.42E-03    1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   3.42E-03    1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   3.42E-03    1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   3.42E-03    1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   3.44E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   3.44E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   3.44E-03    1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   3.44E-03    1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   3.48E-03    1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   3.48E-03    1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   3.58E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   3.58E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   3.64E-03    1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   3.64E-03    1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   3.79E-03    1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   3.79E-03    1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   3.80E-03    1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   3.80E-03    1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   3.95E-03    8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   3.95E-03    8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   4.01E-03    1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   4.01E-03    1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   4.09E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   4.09E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   4.22E-03    1.86E+01
-2.00E-02   4.22E-03    1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   4.22E-03    1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   4.22E-03    1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   4.22E-03    1.85E+01
-2.00E-02   4.24E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   4.24E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   4.25E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   4.25E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   4.27E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   4.27E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   4.27E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   4.27E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   4.42E-03    1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   4.42E-03    1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   4.50E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   4.50E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   4.62E-03    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   4.62E-03    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   4.76E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   4.76E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   4.82E-03    1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   4.82E-03    1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   4.99E-03    1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   4.99E-03    1.83E+01
-2.00E-02   5.01E-03    1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   5.01E-03    1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   5.01E-03    1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   5.01E-03    1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   5.02E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   5.02E-03    1.82E+01
-2.00E-02   5.06E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   5.06E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   5.09E-03    1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   5.09E-03    1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   5.10E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   5.10E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   5.20E-03    8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   5.20E-03    8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   5.25E-03    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   5.25E-03    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   5.39E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   5.39E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   5.40E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   5.40E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   5.49E-03    1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   5.49E-03    1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   5.68E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   5.68E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   5.73E-03    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   5.73E-03    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   5.73E-03    1.81E+01
-2.00E-02   5.75E-03    1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   5.75E-03    1.80E+01
-2.00E-02   5.80E-03    1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   5.80E-03    1.77E+01
-2.00E-02   5.86E-03    1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   5.86E-03    1.73E+01
-2.00E-02   5.92E-03    1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   5.92E-03    1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   5.96E-03    1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   5.96E-03    1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   5.96E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   5.96E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   6.18E-03    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   6.18E-03    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   6.24E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   6.24E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   6.24E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   6.24E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   6.41E-03    9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   6.41E-03    9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   6.45E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   6.45E-03    1.78E+01
-2.00E-02   6.50E-03    1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   6.50E-03    1.76E+01
-2.00E-02   6.51E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   6.51E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   6.56E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   6.56E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   6.59E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   6.59E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   6.63E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   6.63E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   6.69E-03    1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   6.69E-03    1.67E+01
-2.00E-02   6.77E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   6.77E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   6.86E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   6.86E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   7.03E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   7.03E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   7.03E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   7.03E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   7.13E-03    1.75E+01
-2.00E-02   7.16E-03    1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   7.16E-03    1.74E+01
-2.00E-02   7.17E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   7.17E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   7.26E-03    1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   7.26E-03    1.71E+01
-2.00E-02   7.29E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   7.29E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   7.37E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   7.37E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   7.40E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   7.40E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   7.46E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   7.46E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   7.54E-03    9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   7.54E-03    9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   7.70E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   7.70E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   7.75E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   7.75E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   7.76E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   7.76E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   7.79E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   7.79E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   7.80E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   7.80E-03    1.72E+01
-2.00E-02   7.89E-03    1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   7.89E-03    1.70E+01
-2.00E-02   8.02E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   8.02E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   8.04E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   8.04E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   8.05E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   8.05E-03    1.66E+01
-2.00E-02   8.11E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   8.11E-03    1.58E+01
-2.00E-02   8.32E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   8.32E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   8.34E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   8.34E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   8.42E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   8.42E-03    1.61E+01
-2.00E-02   8.43E-03    1.69E+01
-2.00E-02   8.46E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   8.46E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   8.49E-03    1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   8.49E-03    1.68E+01
-2.00E-02   8.60E-03    9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   8.60E-03    9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   8.65E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   8.65E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   8.66E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   8.66E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   8.79E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   8.79E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   8.80E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   8.80E-03    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   8.87E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   8.87E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   8.96E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   8.96E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   9.03E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   9.03E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   9.09E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   9.09E-03    1.64E+01
-2.00E-02   9.13E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   9.13E-03    1.45E+01
-2.00E-02   9.14E-03    1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   9.14E-03    1.53E+01
-2.00E-02   9.23E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   9.23E-03    1.62E+01
-2.00E-02   9.26E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   9.26E-03    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   9.40E-03    1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   9.40E-03    1.56E+01
-2.00E-02   9.46E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   9.46E-03    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   9.50E-03    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   9.50E-03    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   9.56E-03    9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   9.56E-03    9.25E+00
-2.00E-02   9.60E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   9.60E-03    1.57E+01
-2.00E-02   9.72E-03    1.60E+01
-2.00E-02   9.76E-03    1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   9.76E-03    1.52E+01
-2.00E-02   9.79E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   9.79E-03    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   9.81E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   9.81E-03    1.59E+01
-2.00E-02   9.84E-03    1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   9.84E-03    1.44E+01
-2.00E-02   9.85E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   9.85E-03    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   9.96E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   9.96E-03    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.19E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.48E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.01E-02    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.02E-02    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.02E-02    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.03E-02    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.03E-02    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.04E-02    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.04E-02    1.54E+01
-2.00E-02   1.04E-02    9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   1.04E-02    9.21E+00
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.43E+01
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   1.05E-02    1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    1.49E+01
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.07E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.47E+01
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.08E-02    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.10E-02    1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   1.10E-02    1.41E+01
-2.00E-02   1.10E-02    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   1.10E-02    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   1.11E-02    1.50E+01
-2.00E-02   1.11E-02    1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   1.11E-02    1.29E+01
-2.00E-02   1.11E-02    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.11E-02    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.12E-02    9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   1.12E-02    9.12E+00
-2.00E-02   1.13E-02    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.13E-02    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.13E-02    1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   1.13E-02    1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   1.13E-02    1.46E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    1.37E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    1.17E+01
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.15E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.16E-02    1.42E+01
-2.00E-02   1.16E-02    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.16E-02    1.38E+01
-2.00E-02   1.17E-02    1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   1.17E-02    1.27E+01
-2.00E-02   1.18E-02    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   1.18E-02    1.31E+01
-2.00E-02   1.18E-02    1.39E+01
-2.00E-02   1.18E-02    8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   1.18E-02    8.96E+00
-2.00E-02   1.19E-02    1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   1.19E-02    1.33E+01
-2.00E-02   1.20E-02    1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   1.20E-02    1.14E+01
-2.00E-02   1.20E-02    1.35E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   1.21E-02    1.26E+01
-2.00E-02   1.22E-02    1.30E+01
-2.00E-02   1.23E-02    8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   1.23E-02    8.71E+00
-2.00E-02   1.24E-02    1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   1.24E-02    1.11E+01
-2.00E-02   1.24E-02    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.24E-02    1.18E+01
-2.00E-02   1.24E-02    1.23E+01
-2.00E-02   1.26E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.26E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.26E-02    1.15E+01
-2.00E-02   1.27E-02    1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   1.27E-02    1.05E+01
-2.00E-02   1.27E-02    8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   1.27E-02    8.31E+00
-2.00E-02   1.28E-02    1.01E+01
-2.00E-02   1.29E-02    7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   1.29E-02    7.67E+00
-2.00E-02   1.30E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.30E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.31E-02    7.29E+00
-2.00E-02   1.32E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.32E-02    0.00E+00
-2.00E-02   1.32E-02    0.00E+00
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your query to make your code snippet compilable, E.g., which document class do you employ, and which LaTeX packages do you load? Also, please be more specific about the nature of the "problem"  you're looking to fix.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you post, this is the first time for my Latex for my Thesis, as below are the package in my Latex \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption,filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

Comment: Thanks. And please do state which problem(s) you're encountering.

Comment: With the current code it is impossible to get the picture you present. First, there is no `z index=3` because you have only three data columns, thus, it must be `z index=2` (when index is starting at `0` as you have provided for `x index`). Then your `x` data column only has the value `-2.00E-02`, but your picture doesn't seem to consist of this value only ...

Comment: Thank you Stefan, my data come from fluid dynamics simulation due to fully develop profiles, I would like to plot the specific section plane to see the difference of 3D velocity surface. I export the data and try to plot it but still have the problems as I post.